# Trying to read all lines in a file and pick out the ones that begin with 'H' or 'S'

Tags: python

I am writing a program that is supposed to read all of a file that contains languages and then rewrite the languages that begin with an `S` or a `H` to another separate file.

However, I am struggling to do so, I'm quite new to Python, and any help would be much appreciated.

The file that has all the languages in is called `myinputfile.txt`
and the one that you rewrite the languages to is called `myoutputfile.txt`.

I haven't got any code yet as im struggling greatly :(

The language file:

```
1. Assamese/Asomiya
2. Bengali/Bangla
3. Bodo
4. Dogri
5. Gujarati
6. Hindi
7. Kannada
8. Kashmiri
9. Konkani
10. Maithili
11. Malayalam
12. Manipuri
13. Marathi
14. Nepali
15. Oriya
16. Punjabi
17. Sanskrit
18. Santhali
19. Sindhi
20. Tamil
21. Telugu
22. Urdu
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
f = open("myinputfile.txt","r")
lang_h = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Please type the contents of the file into the post.  It is difficult to work with an example provided as an image.  Also, please post what you have done so far.  We can help you with specific problems that you are having, but will not write the code for you.

Comment: See [this post](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) for some help with reading and writing files.

Comment: I have edited it, so you can see my code so far and the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first thing you need to do is open the file so that you can see what's in it. [Here is the documentation for that, with examples](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Make sure that you can see it line by line inside of a `for` loop by using the `print` function:

```
for line in file:
   print(line)
```

Now that you can see each line, one at a time, you can `split` it based on a space and take the last value:

```
name = line.split()[-1]
```

`print` the value again to make sure you're getting what you expect.

Now that you have each name, you can check to see if it starts with your desired letter:

```
if name[0] in "SH":
    print(name)
```

If it does, store it in a list (rather than print it as above) and then use the file documentation link I posted to start with to see how to write back out to a file.

Here is a full example to get you going:

```
inFile = open(r"\path\to\names.txt", 'r')

required = "HS"
valid = []

for line in inFile:
    name = line.split()[-1]

    if name[0].upper() in required:
        valid.append(line)

outFile = open(r"\path\to\validNames.txt", 'w')

for line in valid:
    outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: When i use the split command you just showed me, it prints 22.Urdu at the bottom twice

Comment: I've added an example, give that a try

Comment: Thanks so much, helped alot, :D

Answer (score 0):

Read your input file line by line and append all items that start with `S` or `H` to a list. Then you can write the list to your output file. Opening files with `with` is generally recommended.

```
mylist = []

with open('myinputfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = line.split()[1]
        if s.startswith('S') or s.startswith('H'):
            mylist.append(s)

with open('myoutputfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in mylist:
        f.write('%s\n' % line)
```

If you want a numbered output file, you can do

```
with open('myoutputfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(mylist, start=1):
        f.write('{0}. {1}\n'.format(i, line))
```

Comment: Is there any way i can re number the lines in the new file?

Comment: @travistjp What do you mean by that? If you want to keep the numbers, you can append `line` instead of `s`. Or do you want to start a new numbering?

Comment: so once the languages are re written, can you re number them 1-4 somehow?

Comment: So yeah, new numbering like you said

Comment: Thanks that works, except, it shows it as 0 to 3 rather than 1 to 4, sorry that was my mistake for not saying

Comment: @travistjp You can add `start=1` to `enumerate()` to make `i` start at `1` instead of `0`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it simple like this,

```
f = open("myinputfile.txt","r")
lang_h = f.readlines()
for line in lang_h:
    if line.split()[1].startswith("H") or line.split()[1].startswith("S"):
        #do your work with line.
```